# How to get list all name of routes?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

```
export const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Main',
    component: () => import('~/pages/Main.vue'),
    children: [],
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'Auth',
    component: () => import('~/pages/Auth.vue'),
    meta: {
      isAuthPage: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/movies',
    name: 'Movies',
    component: () => import('~/pages/Movies.vue'),
    meta: {
      isAuthPage: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/tv-shows',
    name: 'TVShows',
    component: () => import('~/pages/TVShows.vue'),
    meta: {
      isAuthPage: true,
    },
  },
]
```

I expected `type Pages = 'Main' | 'Auth' | 'Movies' | 'TVShows`

Comment: What effort have you made

Comment: You can't through the `RouteRecordRaw` interface; the type of the name is [just `string | symbol`](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/types/index.ts#L210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by you expected? Do you want to create this type? You could do that like this:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Main',
    component: () => import('~/pages/Main.vue'),
    children: [],
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'Auth',
    component: () => import('~/pages/Auth.vue'),
    meta: {
      isAuthPage: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/movies',
    name: 'Movies',
    component: () => import('~/pages/Movies.vue'),
    meta: {
      isAuthPage: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/tv-shows',
    name: 'TVShows',
    component: () => import('~/pages/TVShows.vue'),
    meta: {
      isAuthPage: true,
    },
  },
] as const

type Pages = typeof routes[number]["name"]
```

Comment: Yes, you did what I wanted to get, you are the best, thank you very much. But I'm wondering what it means [number]

Comment: This does not work with RouteRecordRaw[], i resolved this problem, i created enum of pages